# Logic inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some static information for icons, basically a src key to where the icon is stored:

```
public static function content(array $data): array


$content =      
      'components' => [
      
        [
            ...            
        ],
        
        [
                    'data' => [
                        'icons' => [
                            [
                                'src' => '...',
                            ],
                            [
                                'src' => '...',
                            ],
                            [
                                'src' => '...',
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
        ...
        
         ];

        return $content;
        
}
```

But I want to convert this static information to dynamic. I get several icons with "$icons['data']['icon']" and I want to list them in the same format above but dynamically, but like this doesn't work:

```
'data' => [
                        'icons' => [

                            foreach($icons['data']['icon'] as $icon){
                                [
                                    'src' => $icon['src']
                                ],
                            
                        ]
                    ]
```

Do you know what's the correct approach to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing like this ? This is not the right way. For every element you have to create an array then you can store the arrays in data array.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're trying to achieve. Do you already have data defined in `$data["icon"]` which you want to output somewhere, or are you trying to assign data _into_ it? Your second code snipppet seems to be trying to do both at the same time, which doesn't make much sense and means it's difficult for us to understand the real intent. Please [edit] the question to clarify it and possibly add a bit of context. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the method format to be easier to understand. Basically dd($icons['data']['icon']) returns an array with several items and I want to have those items instead of having the static ones as I have on the method of the question.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you just write `'icons' => $icons["data"]["icon"]` to assign the whole lot all at once? seems like the source and the target are supposed to have the same structure?

Comment: Thanks, that's an option it works. However like that I get more fields/keys that I want to. There is a simple way with this approach to filter only the array columns that are necessary?

Comment: Well its not just filter because the column names returned by "'icons' => $icons["data"]["icon"]" are not the ones I need to return on the content(). On the content() I need only the src column. But on $icons["data"]["icon"] there is no src code, the column that corresponds to the src is called "source" but I needs to be "src" on the content().

Comment: As you only want a single column by the looks of it, you should be able to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: Ah ok. That's why you should always provide a [mre] of your issue including all relevant data!

Comment: In that case I suggest using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php to transform the structure.